# Raspi CPU is not working?

Tags: pi-2, boot-issues

My Raspi 2B is not booting properly now and it is hanged with instruction cpu1/2/3  is stopped during boot. Is my raspi getting damage or not? I used 5V 700mA power adaptor and some time I used 5V 2A adaptor. After power ON, during boot process Broadcom CPU IC was heating up. What is wrong with my raspi?  Please, help me!

Comment: just an idea here but try putting in the 2A one? I use them all the time, maybe your amps on the 700MA one is too low to handle the RPI?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware fault. The CPU IC should not get really hot unless you are maxing out the CPU/GPU with work... even then it only gets warm 40-50celcius. You should consider getting a replacement.